# pytorchでdeep learningの画像分類モデルを作成しています。

Tags: python, pytorch

モデルのloss関数の一部にtorch.sqrt()をしようしたところ、backward時にnanが発生する問題に突き当たりました。
torch.sqrt()に入力されるベクトルの要素の大きさがとても小さいことが原因のようです。

torch.sqrt()のinputが小さいとbackward時に1/(2*torch.sqrt())がinfになるようです...

何か対処法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、お教えいただければ幸いです。

***エラーメッセージ***

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "main_label_grad.py", 
line 504, in <module> model_g = main() 
File "main_label_grad.py", 
line 459, in main tr_acc, tr_acc5, tr_los, grad_train, last_v4 = train(train_loader, net_c, net_t, optimizer_c, optimizer_t, epoch, args, log_G, args.noise_dim, grad_train_old=None, v4=None) 
File "main_label_grad.py", 
line 320, in train loss_trans.backward() 
File "C:\Users\GUESTUSER\.conda\envs\tf37\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", 
line 118, in backward torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph) 
File "C:\Users\GUESTUSER\.conda\envs\tf37\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", 
line 93, in backward allow_unreachable=True) # allow_unreachable flag RuntimeError: Function 'SqrtBackward' returned nan values in it’s 0th output.
```

上記のloss_transがモデルの目的関数で、以下の関数の1つ目の返り値に該当します。
以下の関数(new_norm)の return torch.sqrt(v4_ema)のv4_emaが小さくてnanになってしまっております。

```
def new_norm(v, epoch, iter, last_v4=None): 
　v2 = torch.pow(v,2) 
　v4 = torch.pow(v,4) 
　v4_ema = ema(v4, epoch, iter, last_v4) 
　epsilon = torch.ones(v4_ema.size(0)) * 1e-10 epsilon = epsilon.cuda() 
　return (v2/(torch.sqrt(v4_ema)+epsilon)).sum()/v4_ema.size(0), v4_ema
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/215645

Comment: infになってしまう時のinputの値は完全に0でしょうか？分数の時にinfとならないように分母に十分小さな値(例えば1e-5)を足しておいても同じエラーになりますか？

Comment: infになってしまう時の値は完全に0ではないのですが、1e-13とかになります。これに対して、1e-5とかを足しちゃうと目的の関数が機能しないと考えておりました。

Comment: 1e-5とかを足すと同じエラーは出ませんでした

Comment: 入力値が1e-5とかよりも、小さい場合に、1e-5とかを足すのは、多分話が違うのではと思うのですが、他に解決策等ありますでしょうか

Comment: kobabu_wrap さんのコメントのとおり、infを回避するために1e-5を加えるのは意味があるかもしれません。あると思います。損失関数の計算を継続するためのテクニックと理解しています。※ゼロから作るDeepLearningのP91で学んだことです。

Comment: 私の理解では、1e-5を足していいのは、元の値に対して、影響を与えないほど1e-5が小さいあたいの場合という認識なのですが、今回のように元の値がとても小さい場合でも足してしまってよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 私の考えは、「損失関数で結果を出すため精度は割り切る」です。個々の値が変化しても、大小関係が逆転しないなど、全体に対して影響が小さければよいと思います。元の値がとても小さい場合、たとえ２倍になっても全体には影響しないと思います。大半のデータがとても小さくて影響がある場合は正規化(※)などデータの分布をばらす必要があると思います。まずは結果を出すため割り切ってはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

PyTorchの場合に限らず、`sqrt(x)` は微分が `1 / (2 * sqrt(x))` になるので、xが0になると `sqrt` の微分がinfになってしまい、そのために、以後の計算の過程でNaNが出ているのだと思います。

安直には0に近い値値が出ないように `torch.sqrt(torch.clamp(x, min=1.0e-6))` のように下駄を履かせてあげれば、エラーは出なくなるのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

原因についてはtatsy の言う通りなのですが　torch.clampを使うと勾配が消されてしまいbackwardの時に影響がでるのでtorch.sqrt(x+1e-6)とした方がいいです